# Decode Image using Xamarin.Andoid to send it to web service

Tags: c#, android, bitmap, xamarin.android

I am developing an Android App using Xamarin Studio in order to capture a picture and then send it to a web service.

The steps are:

1. Capture the picture and store it on the phone.
2. The web service receives an object as argument. This object contains the image in Base64. This is achieved in the following line:

`oImagenFace.ImagenDocumento =(string)Base64ToBitmapDrawableConverter.ConvertBack(BitmapFactory.DecodeFile (imagepath));`

At this point I am getting an `Out of Memory Exception`, but I can not resize the image (as explained here http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) because I need it with the original size. The images are about 200Kb.

Comment: What keeps you from reading the stored image data and convert it directly to base64 instead of decoding it first? Or do you want to send raw RGB data to the server?

Comment: Hi, I don't know how can convert it directly to base64 from path. ConvertBack receives a Bitmap. But if you can show me how to do taht I really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes((imagepath)))

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to skip the BitmapFactory.DecodeFile, and convert the whole file into Base64?
Sg. like this:

```
oImagenFace.ImagenDocumento =(string)Base64ToBitmapDrawableConverter.ConvertBack(imagepath);
```

If that won't help, I would try to read the file by chunks and convert that parts to Base64.

Answer (score 0):

#### Upload Image on Web Server using Android / C# {Xamarin}

> This is Just Small Piece of Code. it can send any image from Android to your Web
>   Server.

```
System.Net.WebClient Client = new System.Net.WebClient();
Client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream");
byte[] result = Client.UploadFile("localhost/FolderName/upload.php", "POST", path);
string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result, 0, result.Length);
```

> Here is the PHP Code {upload.php}. Create a Folder name { Uploads } in
>   your Application.

```
<?php

   $uploads_dir = 'uploads/'; //Directory to save the file that comes from client application.      
   if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)       
   {      
     $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];     
     $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];    
     move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");     
   }
?>
```